# XSLT (numbering nested divs in TEI Simple)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am using TEI Simple and want to add numbering to headers as well as into TOC lines. I understand how it could be built but can’t reach the desired result across parts of a book (`front`, `body`, `back`). It always restarts at the root. My code for two levels (with the rest I do the same):

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='1']/tei:head" mode="toc">
  <fo:block font-size="12pt">
    <xsl:number format="1. " count="tei:div[@n='1']" level="multiple"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='2']/tei:head" mode="toc">
  <fo:block font-size="12pt">
    <xsl:number format="1.1. " count="tei:div[@n='1']|tei:div[@n='2']" level="multiple"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Apparently, I mark any div with `n` attribute. I apply the template for the whole `text` part of the file. The result looks like this:

```
[Front]
1. First
  1.1. First of First
[Body]
1. Second
```

The precise XPaths are:

```
TEI/text/front/div[@n="1"]/head
TEI/text/body/div[@n="1"]/head
TEI/text/back/div[@n="1"]/head
```

… and, obviously:

```
TEI/text/front/div[@n="1"]/div[@n="2"]/head
TEI/text/body/div[@n="1"]/div[@n="2"]/head
TEI/text/back/div[@n="1"]/div[@n="2"]/head
```

**UPDATE**

I have decided for a bit more strict book structure. Typically, it is not common to number front and back matter. Now I am using this and it works properly (I guess it could be possible to mix everything together for all main parts but this way is more reasonable for me. I use it for 8 levels.) *However, I wonder if there is another, much smarter way of doing this. The code seems a bit clumsy with increasing levels.*

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='1']/tei:head[ancestor::tei:front and ancestor::tei:back]" mode="toc">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::tei:div)"/>
  <fo:inline>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='1']/tei:head[ancestor::tei:body]" mode="toc">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::tei:div)"/>
  <fo:inline>
    <xsl:number format="1. " count="tei:div[@n='1'][ancestor::tei:body]" level="multiple"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='2']/tei:head[ancestor::tei:body]" mode="toc">
  <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::tei:div)"/>
  <fo:inline>
    <xsl:number format="1.1. " count="tei:div[@n='1'][ancestor::tei:body]|tei:div[@n='2'][ancestor::tei:    body]" level="multiple"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think the result is as defined, as numbering with `level="multiple"` is based on counting preceding siblings and if the `div` elements are inside different parent elements (e.g. `front`, `body`) then they are not siblings. I wonder whether you cannot delegate the numbering to the result format, i.e., XSL-FO, does it not have any numbered or ordered lists you could create?

Comment: It doesn't look like XSL-FO has some automatic numbering scheme like HTML or CSS offers, so you either need to create a temporary tree in your XSLT that puts those `div` elements under a common parent and then you could number them as you currently try in XSLT or you would need to try to compute number of preceding `div` elements yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short sample, if you use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='1']/tei:head" mode="toc">
  <fo:block font-size="12pt">
    <xsl:number format="1. " value="count(preceding::div[@n = 1]) + 1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

you should get the main number as `1.`, `2.`. For the minor numbering I am not sure whether you want a sequence across the different sections or whether there you want to restrict the count to each section, for the first option use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='2']/tei:head" mode="toc">
  <fo:block font-size="12pt">
    <xsl:number format="1.1 " value="count(preceding::div[@n = 1]) + 1, count(preceding::div[@n = 2]) + 1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

for the second

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div[@n='2']/tei:head" mode="toc">
  <fo:block font-size="12pt">
    <xsl:number format="1.1 " value="count(preceding::div[@n = 1]) + 1, count(preceding-sibling::div[@n = 2]) + 1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested but should give you an idea.

An alternative would be to produce the main number with `level="any`, and the second with `level="single"`.

Comment: Thank you, the trick with 'value="..."' allowed to add 1 to the basic level. Sure, the basic level is counted per partes or the whole text (text in my case), nested levels are counted only within the parent. I am curious whether this solution is the only one possible. If not, I will mark this question as answered! (I had thought it could be associated with the different root element (not siblings) but wondered why something like '//tei:div' does not work then.

Comment: As I wrote, an alternative should be to use two `xsl:number`, the first with `level="any"`, the second with `level="single"`, see http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mA.

Comment: Thanks, I have done a couple of tests but none of them passed. I have changed the book’s structure a bit and it works. I am trying to build up a bit universal stylesheet–for authoring process in a publishing house.